# При запросе через Guzzle, источник использует бд от инициатора запроса

Tags: php, база-данных, laravel, openserver

Такая дилемма: 
  есть 2 проекта на laravel, работают на openserver, и с проекта 1 нужно сделать http запрос на проект 2, про при запросе получается вот такой результат: проект 2 говорит, что таблицы не существует.. но вот только он пытается эту таблицу найти в бд проекта 1. Почему так? ели делать запрос с Postman - все ок

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте куда и откуда вы шлёте запросы. Скорее всего вы сами заблуждаетесь и не понимаете, что происходит. Фактически не имеет значение каким образом вы делаете запросы по HTTP: Postman, Guzzle - это просто http-клиенты.

Comment: нет, я на 100% уверен, что все хорошо. Я понимаю, что это http-клиенты, вот только guzzle отправляется через phpCurl. 

Шлю с сервера 1 на 2 - 100%..
с postman  - запрос на сервер 2 - все ок.
с guzzle|file_get_contents - 500, говорит, что пытается найти таблизу из бд сервера 1, но понятно что не находит.

Comment: @RuslanMirzapulatov Вы сами вдумайтесь в то, что говорите :) Вы шлёте двумя разными http-клиентами запрос на один и тот же url и получаете разный результат. Такого быть не может, ну или же у вас отличаются headers в запросе и каким-то образом от хедеров зависит конфигурация приложения :)